# How to have a default "NULL" value for an unsigned integer (ex: NaN to floating points)?

Tags: c, arrays, int

I am trying to write some code that will accept either one or two 16-bit hex value from the user and store it in some register. Now these values are stored in a `uint16_t` array of size 2.

This array is then passed to the function that will pass these values one bit at a time. My problem is, if the user only inputs one 16-bit value, then I want to only write that one word, but if the user types two values, then both should be passed to the register.

As of now, I have the check for one or two words, simply being if the second 16-bit value in the array is ==0x0000, then the user only wrote one value.

**How can I check to see if there is only one value, without using the value of the number as its test case?**

For example: floating-point values have NaN, so I could use isnan() instead of checking to see if the value was 0x0000.

Comment: There is no 16 bit value which effectively states it is not a *valid* 16 bit value (this *does* exist for floating point numbers). Add a flag, or make the arguments 32-bit where a value outside of the 16-bit range signifies "invalid".

Comment: Why not pass an array length (1 or 2 in your case) to the function?

Comment: Try using `isnan((short)val)`, since isnan() also works with any integral type (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan). Maybe it also works with uint16_t, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Tetramputechture: If you pass an integer to `isnan`, it's converted to `double`, and the function returns `false`. `isnan` is not meaningful for integer arguments. There is no integer "not-a-number" value.

Comment: @KeithThompson Alright, I was unsure of that. Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2):

Decide on an unused value, which will only be used for this purpose.

You could use `UINT16_MAX`, which is the maximum value `uint16_t` can hold, defined in stdint.h.

Just make sure that the now changed maximum value is used as one less:

```
#define MY_UINT16_MAX (UINT16_MAX-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent to floating point NAN for integer types. All possible values are valid integers. You have a couple of options if you need to model an integer that can be null/invalid/undefined.

1. Set aside a *sentinel* value that is reserved to indicate that the value is null.
2. Maintain a boolean flag in parallel with the actual value that indicates that the value is null.

Now, in your scenario, what you actually have is an array whose length is determined at runtime. Simply keep track of the length separately from the array and then there is no need for any of the above.

Answer (score 2):

You could use larger integers, as they would allow you to simulate what you need:

```
uint32_t arr[2] = {1 << 16, 1 << 16};
```

Testing `arr`'s elements for `>= (1 << 16)` tells you no 16bit value had been read.